# Having issues to create sub-folder in Apache2 in Ubuntu 14.x

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, apache2

My primary goal is to create and use 2 sub-folder for two separate section of the website to run in Laravel on Apache2.

1. www.example.com
2. www.example.com/cmadmin

My config looks like as below. The issue is the top domain is working fine but the "www.example.com/cmadmin" is showing the Folders paths in the browser rather the desired website.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        <Directory "/var/www/html">
            AllowOverride all
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>

       Alias /cmadmin/ /var/www/html/cmadmin/public
        <Directory "/var/www/html/cmadmin/public">
            Options All
            AllowOverride all
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

#        DirectoryIndex index.html        
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example_com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example_codomo.key
        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                        downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
</VirtualHost>

</IfModule>
```